# How to create a usual non-resizible window with thick border (MFC or WinAPI)

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc

I want to create a window with the following properties:

- Thick border ("double border" as described in MSDN)
- Not resizable
- Icon in the title
- Close button in the title

It sounds so simple and we can find this kind of windows everywhere in Windows. But as soon as I disable ability to resize my window I also lose the thick border. Here is the illustration of my problem:

[image]

The height of my test window's caption bar is slightly less than that of a Shell property dialog, but I would like it to be the same height.

I have tried to use WinSpy and copy all styles from Explorer's window to mine, but this did not help.

Comment: `WS_THICKFRAME` and `WS_SIZEBOX` have the same [value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles). When removing the size box, you're also removing the thick frame. You cannot have one but not the other. Although it doesn't appear that you actually want a thick border anyway.

Comment: @IInspectable, thanks for the details. I still believe it is thick frame what I need. WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME also promising "a double border", but I cannot apply it to my window for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's going on under the hood, but I found two solutions:

- Switch to the newer Platform Toolset (which means drop support of Windows XP)
- Disable resizing by writing custom WM_NCHITTEST handler

The second option is quite simple and I do not want drop Windows XP support for a silly reason. Job is done:

```
LRESULT CListEditorDlg::OnNcHitTest(CPoint point)
{
    LRESULT retVal = CDialog::OnNcHitTest(point);
    switch (retVal)
    {
        case HTBOTTOM:
        case HTBOTTOMLEFT:
        case HTBOTTOMRIGHT:
        case HTLEFT:
        case HTRIGHT:
        case HTTOP:
        case HTTOPLEFT:
        case HTTOPRIGHT:
            retVal = HTBORDER;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```